# Element in list-of-elements when element is an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

What would be the correct syntax in Postgres to do something like:

```
SELECT ARRAY[4,5,6] IN ARRAY[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

Some dbs have a `list_contains` or `IN UNNEST(arr_expr)` to do something like the above but I haven't been having luck checking in Postgres docs.

Comment: Wrapping the last part in `(...)` is correct syntax.  I don't know if it is the correct semantics, you didn't tell us what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your containing array has sub-arrays all the same length you should be able to use the array-contains operator

```
richardh=> SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3] <@ ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2,3], ARRAY[4,5,6]];
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

However, be aware it is more "generous" in its matching than you might want

```
richardh=> SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3] <@ ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2,3,4], ARRAY[4,5,6,7]];
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

See [the manuals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`UNNEST` "flattens" multidimensional arrays, so it is not useful here

array-contains (`<@` operator) also internally "flattens" such arrays

You can try to store your data as `JSON(B)` and it will work as expected:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]'::jsonb) arr_rows
WHERE arr_rows = '[4,5,6]'::jsonb;

SELECT count(*)
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]'::jsonb) arr_rows
WHERE arr_rows = '[4,5,6,7]'::jsonb;

SELECT count(*)
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]'::jsonb) arr_rows
WHERE arr_rows = '[4,5]'::jsonb;
```